# \s RegEx not capturing new line data

Tags: javascript, regex, netsuite

I am trying to clean up input and put it into a desired way. Basically, we have serialnumbers that are entered several different ways - enter delimited (newline), space, comma, etc.

My problem in my code below in testing is that new line delimited isn't working. According to w3schools and 2 other sites:
The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.
A whitespace character can be:

-A space character

-A tab character

-A carriage return character

-A new line character

-A vertical tab character

-A form feed character

This should mean that I can catch basically any new line. In Netsuite, the user is entering the value as:

SN1
SN2
SN3

I want this to change to "SN1,SN2,SN3,". Currently the \s RegEx is not picking up the newline? Any help would be appreciated.

**For the record - while I am using Netsuite (CRM) to get the input, the rest of this code is typical javascript and regex work. This is why I am using all 3 tags - netsuite, js, and regex

```
function fixSerailNumberString(s_serialNum){
  var cleanString = '';
  var regExSpace = new RegExp('\\s',"g");
  if(regExSpace.test(s_serialNum)){
    var a_splitSN = s_serialNum.split(regExSpace);
    for(var i = 0; i < a_splitSN.length;i++){
        if(a_splitSN[i].length!=0){
            cleanString = cleanString + a_splitSN[i]+((a_splitSN[i].split(',').length>1)?'':',');
        }
    }
    return cleanString;
  }
  else{
    alert("No cleaning needed");
    return s_serialNum;
  }
}
```

EDITS:
1-I need to handle both if it has spaces (such as "sn1, sn2, sn3" needs to become "sn1,sn2,sn3") and this newline issue. What I have above works for the spaces. 
2- I am not sure if it matters, but the field is a textarea. Does that impact this?

Comment: `s_serialNum.split("\n").join(",");` doesn't work? (instead of the hole function/regex)

Comment: I want to be able to split on both space and \n (will edit above to be clear). Therefore, the space example (that is currently working) of "sn1, sn2, sn3" becomes "sn1,sn2,sn3".I want to be able to split on both space and \n (will edit above to be clear). Therefore, the space example (that is currently working) of "sn1, sn2, sn3" becomes "sn1,sn2,sn3".
Edit: After your comment, i tried what you suggested but with "\\n" and it didn't work.

Comment: @TMann http://jsfiddle.net/506g80ut/ you, probably, have something else there..

Comment: @Cheery like what? All I am entering is: sn1 (hit enter) sn2 (hit enter) sn3 . This then returns out as a String. Something did just dawn on me that may come into play (I will also add above) - the input field is a textarea. Does that change this?

Comment: @TMann check the string in HEX editor, for example. I showed at jsfiddle, that \s works for \r, \n, spaces.. It means that you have something else in your string, can not tell what - not enough info. And use `\\s+` to split by multiple symbols too, not just one.

Comment: @Cheery so what I got when copy pasting the values into a hex editor (HxD) was OD OA for the return. Looking that up, that is Carriage Return followed by Line Feed. But both of these should work in \s, right? Why isn't it seeing it? What can I do?

Comment: @TMann give the code where you enter those values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63960/discussion-between-tmann-and-cheery).

Comment: Not directly relevant to your problem, but there's no need to construct a regexp from a string using `new RegExp`. Just us a regexp literal `/.../`.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but consider using `\s+` instead of just `\s`. In some cases, a newline might be a combination of `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

@Cheery found why this was happening. As I said, I got the data from Netsuite and was using the API to get the data. In the UI of Netsuite this data did look like each line was on a new line, however, when doing a console.log the values were not.

Example:

UI displayed: 

sn1

sn2

sn3

Console.log displayed:

sn1sn2sn3

I was assuming the UI translated into the actual value and didn't think to check what the string was.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite multi-select fields (like the Serial Numbers transaction column) usually return all selected values as a single string, as you've noted with "sn1sn2sn3"; however, each of these values is actually separated by a non-printing character `\x05`. Try `.split(/\x05/).join(',')`